# Webform new line after the field name

Tags: webforms

I have created my first webform in drupal 8. However, I found that some of the fields such as "Telephone", "Email" are showing the field name and the textfield on the same line. However, for the text field such as "Name" and "Subject" (Also a textfield), the field name and textfield are showing on different line.

I haven't done any setting on those 4 fields. I would like to ask if I could do some settings such that the textfield is always under the field name?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Telephone and Email are field which looks like textfield but actually are not of type textfield. Instead, they are of field type `telephone` and `email` respectively, which was introduced when Drupal 8 was released.

In order to show field title and field input in same line use below steps,

1. Edit the individual field.
2. Go to form display setting and open the title display dropdown.
3. Select `Inline` option.

[image: Title display setting]

Comment: I would like to ask how to make the Email input field in another row of the Email Label? Thanks